# Pasar de una activity a un xml sin clase.

Tags: java, android

Buenas soy nuevo en Android, estoy haciendo un proyecto sumamente sencillo pero mi consulta es quiero pasar con un Intent de una clase al presionar un botón a un Xml sin clase. Es posible?? Dado que si hago clase y xml mi proyecto se volvería demasiado pesado pienso y al ser nuevo no se que hacer. Gracias de ante mano y perdón la ignorancia.

Comment: Una solución es utilizar Fragment. Esto te permite cargar diferentes layouts de vistas XML sin tener que cambiar de clase.
Esta opción, sin embargo, puede hacer que el código de la clase sea menos legible en caso de que sea extenso. Crear una nueva clase no hace que la aplicación coja mucho más peso. Esta opción te permite tener todo más ordenado y el código más legible (en caso de que sea extenso). A mi parecer una manera de progarmar no es mejor que la otra, ya que cada uno tiene su forma de programar y con la que se encuentra más cómodo. Así que puedes utilizar la que mejor te parezca.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta dado a que soy nuevo en esto pensé que tener demasiadas clases hacia que mi proyecto tuviera demasiado peso. Entonces esta en contra de hacer muchas clases dado a que necesito muchos archivos xml. Entonces lo haré más ordenado con sus clases aunque solo necesite su parte gráfica.

Comment: Quizá no me haya explicado del todo bien. Si tienes muchas vistas XML, es preferible utilizar los Fragments ya que sólo tendría que cargar la vista y la RAM sufriría menos. En caso de tener pocas vistas daría igual que lo hicieras con las clases ya que cogería poco peso más. Pero el hacer excesivas clases si que podría cogerte mucho peso y darle mucho trabajo a la RAM.

Comment: Todos iniciamos sin saber mucho acerca del tema, así que no te preocupes, este es el lugar correcto para preguntar pero realizalo en base a [ask] para que las preguntas sean de ayuda a todos lo desarrolladores. En realidad el layout de un xml es ligero, lo que implicaría peso serían imágenes que agregues a este layout y en realidad puedes realizar un Intent a una Activity que no tenga xml esto es posible. Saludos.